# Entering a DIV automatically opens link into iframe

Tags: iframe, html, href

I've a "position: fixed" iframe on top of the page, above that, an horizontal menu (fixed too).
Each menu button scrolls the whole page to a selected div.

Is there a way to automatically open a link once reached that div?
I need to automatically load "iframe content 1" entering "div #1", "iframe content 2" entering "div #2", etc.

Page has jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lets see if this works for you:

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  var targetOffset = $('#div1').offset().top; 
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete, lets load content
     $('#div1').html($('#iframe1').contents());
  });
});

/**
For the contents() to work the iframe must be getting the content from the same domain
*/
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm working on that.
With "#iframe1" what are you referring to?

I've an iframe named "frame", in which I load the page that needs to be loaded (from the same domain).

<a href="pagename.html" target="frame">link</a>

Comment: I dont use target="frame". I was assuming you had the #iframe1 already loaded with the html, so i am scrolling to the div and when its is done i am loading the iframe contents the #div1